# Still music playing when call the activity of player agin from intent?

Tags: android

```
public class Music extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;

private ImageButton btnPlaylist;

private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private  MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ImageButton homeButton;
ImageButton backButton;
private boolean isActivityRestarting;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forword_btn);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backword_btn);

    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);

    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();


     homeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("org.example.app.betar.HOME");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        });

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("org.example.app.betar.HOME");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        });
    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event
     * plays a song and changes button to pause image
     * pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event
     * Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event
     * Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });









    /**
     * Button Click event for Play list click event
     * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
     * */
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed
 * if repeat is ON play same song again
 * if shuffle is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF

        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }


@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
     return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}


}
```

I built the music player using android this player is one from more activity in this app i call activity player from home page but when i back to home page then call activity of player again  you play the song again and still the old music playing

i need when i call activity player continue playing song as back to now plying

I use startActivity to call activity player from home page

plz helpe Me

Answer (score 0):

In Android onBackPress() or onPause() Stop the media player and finish() the Activity.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand But i stop onBackPress() because i Create back button.

Comment: 'imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
 
    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("org.example.app.betar.MUSIC");
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
   }
 
  });'

Back button to music player

Comment: imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {  mp.stop(); Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("org.example.app.betar.MUSIC"); startActivity(openStartingPoint); finish();} });'

Comment: Thanxx alot but how i can stop MediaPlayer in other Activity 
mp is placed in Music Activity

Comment: easy process is :: define this media player static and access this media player from you stop activity.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the MediaPlayer in an Activity's `onCreate` method without checking if a MediaPlayer instance already exists is not a good idea. You might want to familiarize yourself with the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) in Android. Your Activity may be re-created e.g. if it has been stopped due to being moved to the background, or due to an orientation change if the user tilts the device. So you should at the very least override all relevant callbacks (`onStop`, `onResume`, etc) so that you can release and allocate resources in an appropriate way.

Even better would be to manage the MediaPlayer in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), since services are meant to run for long periods of time in the background. The Android documentation even mentions this particular use-case when describing services: *"For example, a service might play music in the background while the user is in a different application"*.

Comment: Ok Ok Good but i add a runnable to this code and i can play music in the background ,, the problem how i can call mediaplayer with save current playing without playing new music and still old music playing ,, plz Help mee

Comment: Threads and services are not the same thing. Retaining threads if your activity gets destroyed (e.g. by an orientation change) takes a bit of extra work. Putting that aside, when you're about to create the thread that handles media playback, check if you already have a thread running; if you do, don't start another one.

Comment: Mr.Michael you can help me to convert this code to service ,,

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is far too late but hope it works. Assign the mediaplayer mp to be static. such as
private static MediaPLayer mp. This will hold one instance of the mp so that it is just reused and not recreated. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }
```

mp.release edit mp.pause

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.pause();
 }
```